# Moto G 2-gen - can I recalibrate automatic brightness mechanism?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, motorola-moto-g, screen-brightness

Is there any way to recalibrate/reconfigure automatic brightness behavior?

I would like to make it a little bit brighter in low light conditions.

I'm using Moto G 2-gen with KitKat without root access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to calibrate the mechanism normally. The screen brightness values are fixed.

You could use an app like [Lux Auto Brightness](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vito.lux) to manage your screen brightness instead of using the default auto brightness setting. This isn't a perfect solution but it is probably the easiest to implement. Alternatively, you could root your phone and install the Xposed Framework. You could then use a module like Gravitybox to manually set your preferred auto brightness values.